# install numpy on python 3.2 32 bit using windows 7 pro without having pip

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, windows-7, pip

I've got windows 7 pro and have installed python 3.2 (along with other versions) but want 3.2 so that I can use pygame. I cannot get get-pip to work - I just get a syntax error. How can I install numpy?

Answer (score 0):

if you can not use pip, you may try conda or [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), for a version control of python. then you can install numpy easily.